# How to prove lemmas with partial functions?

Tags: isabelle

Could you suggest how to prove this simple lemma?

```
datatype val = BVal bool | IVal int

lemma the_unif:
"the (x :: val option) = the (y :: val option) ⟹ x = y"
  apply (induct x; induct y)
  apply simp
```

I'm trying to prove it by induction, but I stuck on case `⋀option. the None = the (Some option) ⟹ None = Some option`.

`option` may be equal either to `BVal x` or to `IVal x`. It will never be equal to `the None`. So the assumption will always have false value in this cases.

**UPDATE:**

I can prove the following lemma:

```
lemma the_none_ne_the_some:
  "x ≠ the None ⟹ the None ≠ the (Some x)"
  by simp
```

So I guess, that the first lemma can be proven too.

The general lemma can't be proven, because it really doesn't hold:

```
lemma the_unif:
  "the x = the y ⟹ x = y"
```

A counterexample:

```
x = None
y = Some (the None)
```

But in the first lemma neither `x`, nor `y` can be equal to `Some (the None)`. So I can't find a counterexample for the first lemma.

Oh, I've got it, I can prove the following lemma:

```
lemma the_unif:
  "x ≠ Some (the None) ⟹ y ≠ Some (the None) ⟹ the x = the y ⟹ x = y"
  by (induct x; induct y; simp)
```

But how to prove that `x :: val option` implies `x ≠ Some (the None)`?

**UPDATE 2:**

It seems that it is impossible to prove that:

```
lemma val_not_the_none:
  "x = BVal b ∨ x = IVal i ⟹ x ≠ the None"
```

But if the lemmas doesn't hold then they must have a counterexamples? Could you provide one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to prove simply does not hold. `the None` is unspecified – in essence, there's nothing non-trivial you can prove about it. Hence, saying "it will never be equal to `the None`" is vacuous, because you don't know what `the None` is.

Comment: I've added an update to the question. Could you suggest how to prove that `x :: val option` implies `x ≠ Some (the None)`?

Comment: It seems that it is actually impossible... But in this case the lemma must have a counterexample. And if it doesn't have one, maybe it can be proven by contradiction?

Comment: There is neither an example nor a counterexample. As I said, it's unspecified.